# How to use modal with angular-ui efficient way (angular style )?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Modal (ui.bootstrap.modal) and I have seen 2 different implementations for this:

**1. Declare the controller modal instance in the modal declaration**

```
/* 1 file ModalDemoCtrl.js*/    

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')
  .controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: function(){
        // stuff
      },
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

**2. Declare the controller modal instance separate from the parent controller**

```
/* first file ModalDemoCtrl.js*/  

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')
  .controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller:'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
  });

/* second file ModalInstanceCtrl.js*/ 

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')
  .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {
    //stuff
  });
```

---

**Questions**

---

a) Which implementation is suitable for a large angular web application ?

b) With **implementation 2** will I have dependency issues later on, because of the members that will be resolved and passed to the controller as locals (*resolve (Type: Object)*) ?

c) With **implementation 1** will I increase the number of code lines in my js file ( the controller) and will be harder to understand the logic ?